# Rails Database design and multiple subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, subdomain

I'm actually starting a new project and I need some advice regarding the database design. Let me explain a little bit first.

I'm gonna build this application on the top of Ruby On Rails. Each new user gonna have his own url such as `username.domain.com`.

So far so good, but what about the database? Should I use just one single database and handle everything from there using the user session information to retreive datas, or should I create a new database for every users?

Some poeple suggested me to use a prefix on my tables' name such as WP or Drupal does to handle multiple website but I really found that solution DIRTY and not maintainable on the long run since I need to duplicate all my tables for every users. What if I have 10.000 users and 100 common tables? Messy no?

Every ideas are welcome.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates did a Railscast on multitenancy - it's a 'pro' episode and requires a subscription, but has great information on this topic.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

Comment: That looks like an interesting article.  Could you give us a précis so we don't have to subscribe to get to the bottom line?

Comment: In this case, the approach is to put a user_id on all sub tables, add default scopes to these models, around_filter on the application controller to set current_tenant, and some other helpers.  You really should watch the episode - Railscasts are worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the use cases.  Are these users separate and you are just providing a hosting service?  If so you might want separate databases.  Or are they related, as in a social network and share a lot of functionality in common and would have many joins between their tables. In that case you probably want a single database.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The system will be a managment application  and in that case, can be similar to a social network. Since tables gonna have lots of join and common functionnalities, my first idea was indeed the same as yours, a single database